# FileNet change document status to superseded

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I have a requirement where I need to change the version status of a document to 4 i.e. superseded.

Ex: Let's assume we have a document with version status as 1 i.e. released. I want to change its version status to 4 i.e. superseded.

The catch here is that I'm allowed to check-out, check-in document but I cannot have different versions of this document. Meaning before changing the version status, there was only one version of the document and after changing version status, only one version should remain.

The easiest way I think is of directly updating docVersion table but I don't want to do that.

Any ideas? Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by design. The purpose of `SUPERSEDED` version status is to indicate that there is the next version.

Tinkering with database is looking for trouble.